# Run python in terminal and don't terminate when terminal is closed

Tags: python, terminal

I need to make static website. So I connected via ssh to some local server, where I want to make a static website. Then I used python to make it work:

```
$ python -m http.server 55550
```

But if I close terminal, then python program is terminated. I want to shut down my computer, but I want to let this process running on that local server, so other people could still access that website.

**How can I do this?** After that, how should I terminate that process later?

Thanks for any help

Comment: this is probably better on the superuser,  but you should look int making it a daemon (using your os's facilities for do that), but based on the shell prompt  you can try `nohup`  using something   `nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 55550` will make that not respond to hup and continue to run if the term proc goes away.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`nohup` shell builtin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup):

```
nohup python -m http.server 55550
```

To terminate the process, simply kill it using the `kill` command, just like any other process.

Answer (score 9):

you can also launch it in background

```
python -m http.server 55550 &
```

then enter

```
disown
```

to detach the process to the current term

Comment: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 55550 & disown
it allowed me to enter more commands in that terminal, but it dont work after I exit ssh

Comment: It should as I do it everyday with many others process I launch ;) You may miss something. :/

Comment: @Windkiller [disown vs nohup](http://www.zzrevi.com/q/answers-difference-between-nohup-disown-and-3886.html) ;)

Comment: Interesting, but problem remains. Once I exit ssh and connection is closed, my proceses die with disown...

Comment: you are sure that before exiting the ssh connection your enter disown just after having enter `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 55550 &` ?

Comment: Im very sure. This server isnt mine. Maybe there is some daemon that collects and terminates some kind of processes... ?

Answer (score 4):

```
screen
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 55550 &
press ctrl+a, then press d
exit

shutdown your computer
...
start your computer
ssh your server
screen -r
```

Comment: if you shutdown the computer the screen process will halt too ...

Comment: @FoxMaSk: the server will not

Comment: you didnt detach the screen before so the exit will end the python process, you need to do crtl-D to detach the screen ; then you can do exit, dont you ?

Comment: @FoxMaSk: not used for several weeks, added