# How to run http.server command in background on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, simplehttpserver

I've requirement to share static html pages within intranet. I figured out that `http.server` is working perfectly for this purpose.

> python -m http.server 8080

Instead of keeping terminal open, I want to run the command in background.

Comment: Take a look at how to run programs via `LaunchDaemon`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move SimpleSocket server into a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334729/how-to-move-simplesocket-server-into-a-background-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer in post

[Run python in terminal and dont terminate it when terminal is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614665/run-python-in-terminal-and-dont-terminate-it-when-terminal-is-closed)

This question can be marked duplicate of above post than one suggested by comment

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram