# Python thread keeps running even after Jupyter Lab is closed and terminal is closed. Is this expected operation?

Tags: python, terminal, task, jupyter, schedule

I am reading data from a BACnet thermostat and storing values in an sqlite3 database ~ every minute using the schedule library.  I realized that the task keeps running even after I close the Chrome browser running Jupyter Lab and the terminal window.  In my case this is a good thing but I assume this is unexpected operation since there are other questions posted on how to intentionally cause this to happen.  Is this expected operation?  I have to assume it is either bac0 or the schedule library keeping the process alive but that is my question.  I'm running Linux Mint.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import BAC0
import sqlite3

myIPAddr = '192.168.0.65/24'
bacnet = BAC0.connect(ip = myIPAddr)

def SetTempFromSchedule():
def StoreData():
def SetHeatTemp():
def SetCoolTemp():

schedule.every().minute.at(":00").do(setTempFromSchedule)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[Full python program](https://engrokstate.blogspot.com/2022/12/python-program-to-change-set-point-on.html)

I was expecting the process to stop when Jupyter Lab and the terminal window which launched Jupter Lab were closed.

[Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614665/run-python-in-terminal-and-dont-terminate-when-terminal-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out what is going on I just accomplished the task in a different way.  I converted the .ipynb to a .py file using the 'Save and Export' function in Jupyter.  Then I executed the .py script every minute using crontab as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab)  This also allowed be to delete the while loop and the schedule library which are now unnecessary.